# How to make a template table in SQL that pulls specific columns from other different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have multiple tables with multiple columns, but for this question say I just have three tables with one column each:

table1:

| id | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 14 |
| 2 |  | 11 |

table2:

| id | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 14 |  | 4 |
| 101 | 16 | 12 | 19 |

table3:

| id | F |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 6 |
| 8765 | 11 |

Desired output:

mainTable:

| id | tableName | columnName | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | table1 | A | 20 |
| 1 | table1 | B | 14 |
| 2 | table1 | B | 11 |
| 100 | table2 | C | 14 |
| 101 | table2 | C | 16 |
| 101 | table2 | D | 12 |
| 101 | table2 | E | 19 |
| 8765 | table3 | F | 11 |

As you could notice, I'd like the query to also have a condition where it only chooses to insert into the main table if the column value is greater than 10.

Let me know if I can add any further information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `union` and a CTE for clarity to insert your rows with a single `insert`

```
with t as (
    select id, 'table1' Tablename, 'col1' ColumnName, col1 as Value
    from table1
    union all
    select id, 'table2', 'col2', col2
    from table2
    union all
    select id, 'table3', 'col3', col3
    from table3
)
insert into mainTable (id, tableName, columnName, Value)
select id, tableName, columnName, Value
from t
where value > 10
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How would this work with multiple columns, exactly? Like if table1 has 4 columns, and table2 has 8. Do I name each one of them when selecting?

Comment: All tables in a union must have the same columns (not by name, but by data type). If you have 2 tables with different number of columns then provided the data types match for the shared columns, just add `null` (or suitable value) for the missing columns eg `select a, b, c from Table1 union all select x, y, NULL from table2`

Comment: I want the different columns in each source table to end up in the same column in the mainTable. I just made edits to my post. Is something like that possible? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a so-called key/value table. They are generally a nuisance to work with, but you will have your reasons. The query to get from a normal table to a key/value table is to select value by value and union the results.

```
select id, 'table1' as table_name, 'A' as column_name, a as value from table1 where a > 10
union all
select id, 'table1' as table_name, 'B' as column_name, b as value from table1 where b > 10
union all
select id, 'table2' as table_name, 'C' as column_name, c as value from table2 where c > 10
union all
select id, 'table2' as table_name, 'D' as column_name, d as value from table2 where d > 10
union all
...
```

Comment: Well, I see now, that this is what Stu already showed you in their answer. Somehow you just don't seem to have understood that, though. So I don't delete my answer and simply upvote theirs. Maybe you find mine more helpful than theirs for some reason.